# How to enable nodejs profiler for a typecript app?

Tags: typescript, profiling, npx

I am trying to profile an typescript app running on nodejs however, i don't seem to find the way to enable nodejs' profiling .

```
npx --prof ts-node myapp.ts
```

wont' work.  Doing it via environment variables like

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--prof
npx ts-node myapp.ts
```

Gives me an error

```
node: --prof is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

How do I profile this typescript app?
Thanks

Comment: Try with `--perf-prof` instead of `--prof`. Reference - https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/17600

Comment: Except that `--perf-prof` seems to do something rather different than `--prof`.

Answer (score 3):

Try running `node -r ts-node/register --prof myapp.ts`